# childDivider's width in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, expandablelistview, separator

I have this ExpandableListView:

```
<ExpandableListView
  android:id="@+id/pizzaList"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:groupIndicator="@null"
  android:divider="@color/cacaca"
  android:dividerHeight="1dp">
</ExpandableListView>
```

`@color/cacaca` is:

```
<item name="cacaca" type="color">#cacaca</item>
```

The problem is the width of divider is `match_parent` by default, but there is not a dividerWidth. How can I change this value ?

A screenshot:

[image]

Minium API is: `10 2.3.3`
Target: `15`

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the divider's width by creating your own class extending the ExpandableListView, and overwrite its onDraw() method, where you can specify custom measurements to it.

You can opt for a workaround too: set the divider to @null, and create a custom view to your renderers, with a horizontal line (view) at the bottom of each ViewGroup. You can assign the width you wish to this view, and it will look as a divider.

The second approach may be easier to go for, but I it's pricier too in terms of memory usage / layout speed.